# Image popop after clicking submit button for processing form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a popup image when an user clicks on the submit button. The form takes some time to process that's why. The image does pop up fine. But the form won't send. When I delete the jQuery for the popup image it sends the form as it should.

I started with some html:

```
<div id="showProcessingImg">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitForm" value="Send">                                                    
</div>

<div id="page-cover">
    <div id="uncloseable-lightbox">             
    </div>
</div>
```

And of course some jQuery:

```
//POPUP IMAGE   
$('#showProcessingImg').click(function() {
    $('#submitForm').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#saveSignature').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#clearSignature').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#disablePrev').hide();
    $('#page-cover').show();
});

//CHECK IF SIGNATURE IS SAVED                   
$('#submitForm').click(function() {
    if($("#signature").val().length === 0){
        alert("Vul eerst een handtekening in en druk op save.");
      return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

And last but not least the CSS:

```
#page-cover {
    background-color: #888; 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

#uncloseable-lightbox {
    background: url(../images/processing.gif) no-repeat !important;
    background-size: 320px 70px !important;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:40%;
    margin-left:-160px;
    margin-right:-160px;
    width:30%;
    height:15%;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not put the form and\or the fields as `disabled`, put them as `readonly`. Disabled field will not be posted.

Comment: @Athafoud Thanks it does work. But does it prevent the user from clicking the button twice? Thus sending the form twice

Comment: I think it does! But if you want to add an extra layer, you an do `$('#submitForm').off('click')` inside the click function and rebind the event before you 'leave' the function.

Answer (score 0):

The events should be on the submit button not on the div wrapping it.Like this

```
<div id="showProcessingImg">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="signature"> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitForm" value="Send">                                                    
</div>

<div id="page-cover">
    <div id="uncloseable-lightbox">             
    </div>
</div>
```

**Js:**

```
$('#submitForm').click(function() {
     $('#submitForm').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#saveSignature').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#clearSignature').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#disablePrev').hide();
    $('#page-cover').show();
    if($("#signature").val().length === 0){
        alert("Vul eerst een handtekening in en druk op save.");
      return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Css:

```
#page-cover {
    background-color: #888; 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

#uncloseable-lightbox {
    background: url(../images/processing.gif) no-repeat !important;
    background-size: 320px 70px !important;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:40%;
    margin-left:-160px;
    margin-right:-160px;
    width:30%;
    height:15%;
}
```

Code Here: http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/k54b2Lv5/1/